# How to enter values when two div elements having same class names

Tags: html

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pErCV.jpg)

i have to enter value in particular cell but getting error

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-grid-item-container']/table/tr/td[4]/div)[2]")).click();
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-grid-item-container']/table/tr/td[4]/div)[2]")).sendKeys("5.03")
```

Comment: What is your question/could you clarify/give us the full code in text form?

Comment: //i have to enter value in particular cell but getting error driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-grid-item-container']/table/tr/td[4]/div)[2]")).click(); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-grid-item-container']/table/tr/td[4]/div)[2]")).sendKeys("5.03")

Comment: This class is a css class you've applied for style ?

Answer (score 0):

Give different id to different div's. And access it using @id='someid'. 
You can assign I'd to div like this :

```
<div id="someid"></div>
<div id="someotherid"></div>
```

Comment: i am a software tester i can not add div id..here